Dynamic Power Bi measure for negative budget
I'm trying to create a dynamic measure to calculate budget target in %, but the calculation depends on if the sales or budget are negative or positive numbers. The calculation for negative numbers should be like this: 2-(sales/budget) and if both are positive just sales/budget. I've attached the correct result in excel and also the results I'm getting in Power BI that have negative sign but should be positive.
Many thanks
Correct results in Excel and incorrect sign in Power BI
CALCULATION = DIVIDE([SALES],[BUDGET]) + IF(OR(SIGN([SALES])=-1,SIGN([BUDGET])=-1),-2,0)

maybe you can try this
=if(DIVIDE([SALES],[BUDGET]) <0, 2-DIVIDE([SALES],[BUDGET]) ,DIVIDE([SALES],[BUDGET]) )

=IF(AND([Sales] > 0, [Budget] > 0), DIVIDE([Sales], [Budget]), 2 - DIVIDE([Sales], [Budget]))

